# DeepLink to contacts Android from Javascript website not working

Tags: javascript, android, deep-linking

I'm trying to build this feature on a website that pressing a button redirects you to the contacts app to see and save the contact in one touch.

Is my first time working with deeplinks but they seems to not work. I have tried various exaples with contacts and they are not working. But if i invoke for example 36454873 it does.

What am I doing wrong? Any one knows how to invoke the contacts app with some information inside?

Thanks.

Code:

```
function getMobileOperatingSystem() {
   var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;
   if (userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) {
      return 'iOS';
   }
   else if (userAgent.match(/Android/i)) {
      return 'Android';
   }
   else {
      return 'unknown';
   }
}

function onLoad() {
   switch (getMobileOperatingSystem()) {
      case 'Android':
         console.log("Android");
         alert("android");
         window.location.href = "intent://contacts/#Intent;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;type=vnd.android.cursor.dir/person;end";
         break;
      case 'iOS':
         console.log("iOS");
         alert("ios");
// ios is handled. Only android not working
         break;
      default:
         console.log("unknown");
         break;
   }
}
window.onload = onLoad;
```

Answer (score 0):

Case it on php script: $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]

and then call it with android asyncTask.